# Can someone help me visualize this reverse Linked List recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

The problem is to reverse a singly linked list, but I'm a bit stuck with the following code:

```
public ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {

    if(head == null || head.next == null) return head;

    ListNode temp = head.next;
    head.next = null;
    ListNode result = reverseList(temp);
    temp.next = head;
    return result;
}
```

What does line 6 do?

```
temp.next = head;
```

Without it, the result will only return the last element and not a reversed list.

The way I read it is that the code gets to line 5, gets result, goes through line 6, then returns the result at line 7, and keeps repeating until finish. How does line 6 actually affect the code?

I'm having a hard time visualizing this recursion. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

A recursive function solves a problem by making use of smaller versions of the exact same problem. There are two main parts to a recursive function: the base case and the recursive case. The base case is the smallest version of the problem where we provide a solution without having to use recursion. It's where the recursion stops. The recursive case makes the assumption that the smaller versions of the problem provide correct solutions and we use those solutions to solve the larger versions.

reverseList() takes the head node of a linked list as input, reverses each node in the list, and returns the head node of the new reversed list.

Let's say you have a linked list:

```
a->b->c->d->e
```

head points to node a and temp points to node b.

On line 4, node a is disconnected from the original list resulting in two sublists, one containing only a and the other containing the other elements starting with b. Now, assuming that line 5 correctly reverses the sublist starting with b, we have:

```
a
e->d->c->b
```

head still points to a, temp still points to b, and result points to e (the head of the reversed sublist).

In order to correctly reverse our original list, we just add node a (head) to the end of the reversed sublist (temp).

Now the list is:

```
e->d->c->b->a
```

where the new head points to e.

Comment: YES! I get it now! That sublist explanation was where I was stuck. I for some reason couldn't visualize result->e->d... and h->a is two lists and the code simply puts head at the end of result :D

Answer (score 0):

Line 6 only make link between  the nodes. recursion goes all the way to last node and make link reverse.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : Posted full code.

I wrote an alternative that you may understand better. I also set the function as static ( getters and setters not used for more straightforward explanation).

```java
public class ListNode {
    // should be private variables
    int value;    
    ListNode next; 

    ListNode(int val, ListNode nodeList){
        this.value = val;
        this.next = nodeList;
    }

    public static ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {

        if( head.next.next != null) 
            reverseList (head.next);

        head.next.next = head;
        head.next = null;

        return head;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String ret = "";

        if ( next != null ){
            ret = next.toString();
        }       
        ret += String.valueOf(value);
        return ret;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListNode n0 = new ListNode(4, null), 
                n1 = new ListNode(3, n0), 
                n2 = new ListNode(2, n1), 
                n3 = new ListNode(1, n2), 
                n4 = new ListNode(0, n3);

        System.out.println(n4);

        ListNode.reverseList(n4);

        System.out.println(n0); // <-- n4 now is the last item, check n0 instead !
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
43210
01234
```

It may be easier for you to understand it here. Drawing it the *before* and *after* always helps. Like [this](http://commoninterview.com/images/Reverse_Linked_List_Interview_Question.jpg), but only changing the arrows insted of the position of the boxes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm testing your code..doesn't it eventually go back to the beginning and only return the first element? Eg 1>2>3 would only return 1 instead of 3>2>1?

Comment: I will update the post with my complete code. I tested it and worked fine. Take into account that if you have `n0, n1, n2....nX` and you reverse it, the first item now it will be `nX` and not `n0`.